# Acumatica : Custom table schema causes error when publishing

Tags: sql-server, acumatica, erp, acumatica-kb

I've got a custom project that I'm trying to publish on my development environment.
I created a new SQL table called TRActivitySector, and I added its custom table schema to my project.
Now, when I try to publish my project, I get a strange user permission error :

```
Updating the database
Table BAccount(skipped, already applied)
Table CROpportunity(skipped, already applied)
Table POLine(skipped, already applied)
Table POOrder(skipped, already applied)
SharedFilter SharedFilter#AUP§GI000005(skipped, already applied)
.
.
.
SharedFilter SharedFilter#VHU§GI000003(skipped, already applied)
SharedFilter SharedFilter#VHU§GI000009(skipped, already applied)
SharedFilter SharedFilter#VHU§TR402000(skipped, already applied)
SiteMapNode SiteMapNode#6c3aca5e-fd37-49d2-a05b-5a87ab74308b(skipped, already applied)
Table TRMultiCollect(skipped, already applied)
Batch Sql
1 Sql#TRActivitySector

User does not have permission to perform this action.
Query in question:
    exec dbo.sp_fulltext_database 'enable'
    
Time elapsed: 0,0050065 on DEVACUMATICA-VM/trecodec-dev-alexandre-new
Related command: PX.DbServices.Points.MsSql.Commands.CmdCreateFulltextCatalog
File reference: dbo.sp_fulltext_database:27
```

I should add that I just created the SQL database so that it is refreshed from the production. So I guess it is an issue with its configuration ? I tried to grant more permissions to the DefaultAppPool user on the database but that didn't work.

If anyone has an idea as to why this happens and how I could resolve it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you adding your table definition to the customization in a script instead of a Custom Table Schema?

Comment: No, I'm adding it via a custom table schema. I even deleted and redid it to be sure.

I should add that my project compiles and is published on the testing environment that has an Azure DB. The problem only occurs on my dev environment that has a local DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by adding the db_owner permission to the defaultapppool user. I don't know how I missed that...